# PL SQL- Using Dynamic SQL to Generate Delete Statements

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a stored procedure using PL SQL that allows me to find all tables that contain a specific column, and then delete records from those tables that have a specific value in that column.

For example, I want to find all tables that have the column "year" and then delete all records from all of those tables that have the year "2012"(this year will be a parameter that will be entered upon execution)

My attempt at this has been to create a stored procedure, use a cursor to get all of the tables that have this column of "year" and then loop through that cursor using Dynamic SQL which will generate my Delete Statements that I can execute.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE year_deletion
(
p_year  NUMBER --Input of the year for records to be deleted 
)
IS
CURSOR c1 --Cursor that will find all tables that have the YEAR column
IS
    SELECT owner, table_name 
    FROM all_tab_columns 
    WHERE column_name = 'YEAR'
    AND owner = 'GTP';

BEGIN
FOR i IN c1 LOOP    --Loop through all of the tables that the cursor found, generate a SQL statement for each table that will delete all of the records that have the year of p_year
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('SELECT * FROM' ||i.table_name|| 'WHERE YEAR = '||p_year||';'); 
END LOOP;

END;
```

Disclaimer: I am using a Select * From instead of a DELETE * From for testing purposes, I will change this when it this procedure executes correctly.

So far this stored procedure compiles correctly, but gives me an error during execution that a FROM keyword was expected but not found. Is this the best method to use for my purpose?

Comment: You'll need to add space after *FROM* so instead of *...FROM'*, it should be *FROM '*

Comment: || operator will stick i.table_name to FROM, and then you'll have one word like FROMi.table_name, which of course is not what the compiler looking for

Comment: Also you have to add a space in 'WHERE YEAR =... it should be ' WHERE YEAR ='

Comment: Also you may add a Exception block inside the loop and at least print  errors in that cases. for example, if you have some table in wich YEAR is a String and have String values, your sql will fail and the lopp will stop in that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is must be like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' ||i.table_name|| ' WHERE YEAR = :theYear' USING p_year;
```

Note the space after `FROM` and before `WHERE`.

You cannot simply replace `DELETE` by `SELECT ...` for testing because for SELECT you must have an `INTO` clause.

Your entire procedure can be like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE year_deletion(p_year IN NUMBER) IS

   CURSOR c1 IS
   SELECT owner, table_name 
   FROM all_tab_columns 
   WHERE column_name = 'YEAR'
      AND owner = 'GTP';

   res NUMBER;

BEGIN
   FOR i IN c1 LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
         'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' ||i.table_name|| ' WHERE YEAR = :theYear' INTO res USING p_year;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (res ||' rows will be deleted from table '||i.table_name );
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
         'DELETE FROM ' ||i.table_name|| ' WHERE YEAR = :theYear' USING p_year; 
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello you can try the below code. It will surely help you out.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE year_deletion(
    p_year IN  NUMBER --Input of the year for records to be deleted
  )
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT owner,
      table_name
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE column_name = 'YEAR'
    AND owner         = 'GTP')
  LOOP --Loop through all of the tables that the cursor found, generate a SQL statement for each table that will delete all of the records that have the year of p_year
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' ||i.table_name|| ' WHERE YEAR = '||p_year;
  END LOOP;
END;
```